# The Stack Overflow teams Total Economic Impact is broken on mobile

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-for-teams

The Stack Overflow Twitter account tweeted the following link:

https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise/forrester-report?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=Forrester-Report-2019&utm_content=get-the-report

However, when visiting on mobile the captcha and margins are way off, see:

[image]

This is using Chrome 78 on an iPhone X with iOS 13.3.

Comment: If I had invested big money in Stack Exchange that title would scare the sh*t out of me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now looks fixed again.

[image]